# Joined as a customer service executive but have not been assigned any work

Tags: manager

I joined as a customer service executive. Four months gone but still not assigned any work. Job description has also not been given by the company so far. I have, myself, created some roles and responsibilities and showed it to my senior manager. He said OK. I voluntarily took other work also related to the service. But still I feel that I have no work. My reporting Officer also doesnt convey anything to me. What can I do?

Comment: It might help to be a little more specific about at least what you think the problem is. Do you want to be assigned work? Are you worried that if they later realise you've not been doing the work they hired you for, they will decide you're not needed and fire you? Advising what you should do depends on what you want to achieve from this situation.

Comment: Wait, you signed a contract without a job description? How do you know they won't put you on toilet cleaning duty and say that's part of the job?

Comment: A side-question, related to the one @Draken asked: what did you discuss during the interview ?

Comment: Do you really mean "executive" (as in management)? Or do you mean "representative" (as in just a worker)?

Answer (score 7):

Create your own job, as you alread have began to do. You are proactive, and it's a rare and useful quality. As many people seem to need help there, and you are able to help, you can build yourself your own job, rather than waiting to be hit as a pool ball.

Be sure, just, from time to time, to go backwards and look at the coherence of the whole thing. Try to find underlying patterns to the tasks you are doing. Try to give a backbone to the job you are currently creating.

Other than that, someone who does not even need management, and still is useful, is a very valuable asset to have in any team. Build on this strength. Find potential improvements, and do apply them(staying coordinated with other workers, of course). Find useful tasks noone has the time to do. Enjoy your freedom, it's scarce in the corporate environment.

Answer (score -2):

You are an executive? The word "executive" is your starting point and what you have to work with. As an executive, you are management and your job as a manager is to act in a support capacity and work with those above and below you so that they complete their tasks and achieve their individual and team goals consistent with the objectives of the firm. Hopefully, I am not sounding too much like a windbag at this point.

You need to construct a mind map of the needs and pain points of those above and below you so that you can efficiently give them the support they need. You also need to know the priorities of the firm so that you can prioritize your various tasks. You can't fit in the picture if you don't know what the picture is, and you can't know what the picture is unless you collect enough information to be able to draw that picture so that you finally know what the picture is.

Being a manager means you have to work with others so you'll have to network like crazy to get to know everyone, actively participate in meetings and volunteer to follow up on action items. Since no one is telling you much of anything, you'll have to literally create your own job from prefabricated pieces e.g. one-on-one's with your management, meetings, follow-ups on action items cited in meetings, emails or verbally, etc. Find something that you like doing, that you can be good at and that being at is valuable to your management and staff and become the goto person for that something. As a manager, you are the middle person and you are effective as a middle person to the extend that you can act as a faciitator.

Comment: The "executive" in Customer Service Executive is actually not quite a management role, they are pretty much at the bottom rung of the ladder. http://www.aspiringminds.com/featured-profiles/customer-service-executive-0

Comment: @MaskedMan - I learn something new every day. I guess from your source that being a customer service executive is, according to your source, one step above an answering machine, just as being a bank Vice-P is one step above an ATM. For some reason, I thought that being a customer service executive is one level above being a customer service representative. So much for thinking logically. My answer is still sound, though.

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much what an "executive" means in Customer Service. I was rather "amused" by that as well the first time I heard it. I visited a company's office about some setup issue with their software, and was helpfully told that an "executive" would help me shortly. I was not a high-paying customer and the setup issue was rather trivial, so I wondered why an executive would be bothered. When the said "executive" actually showed up, I realized that pretty much everyone in that office was an executive. :)